# Add a post value to a jQuery form object

Tags: jquery, ajax

How do I manually add a new parameter to a form object.  For example I can do the following:

```
var form = $(#formId);

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: action,
    data: form.serialize()
...
```

This will serialize all the fields posted and pass them to ajax.  How can I add an additional field to the `form` object (i.e. one that was not posted by the form)?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
  var form = $(#formId);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: action,
        data: form.serialize()+"&param1=test"
...
```

Comment: Is there not a way to directly add the value to the form object?

Comment: As far as I understand form.serialize() it returns a string with all fields from the form, so you should be able to append another string.

Comment: @V4n1ll4 Add the value as a `type="hidden"` input with the param name that you desire to your form.

Answer (score 0):

i am using serializeObject:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function () {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

and then:

```
var params = $('#formId').serializeObject();
params[...] = '....';
```